# Partition disk after deleting the original partition

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, startup

I have a MacbookPro 2017 running on macOS Big Sur version 11.2 and I installed Windows using Bootcamp without any errors on the first time but I was unaware of the space that was needed for this so I decided to delete this partition and reclaim the space again to the Macintosh HD and now the space appears as available.

The problem I am having right now is that I want to re-partition the drive to provide more space for the Windows partition, but now when I run Bootcamp again I get the error **"Your disk could not be partitioned. An error occurred while partitioning the disk. Please run First Aid from within Disk Utility to check and fix the error"**

I already ran the First Aid, turned off the Firevault, tried to run `/sbin/fsck -fy` on single user mode and got the error **"no such file or directory"** so as of now, I got no luck to provide a solution to reinstall Windows.

Here is the print out of running `diskutil list` in terminal:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         250.7 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     127.8 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 697.0 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                613.7 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            16.4 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 16.4 GB    disk1s5s1
```

When I ran the First Aid in Recovery mode, I also found two errors on the Macintosh HD - Data partition:

```
error: Cross Check: Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (1) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (0) for extent (0x18536df +1)

error: Cross Check: Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (1) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (0) for extent (0x2963359 +1)
```

Comment: So at the moment your total storage is split between the macOS installation and the free space previously taken by Windows?

Comment: Had you used Boot Camp to remove it it would have worked. Doing it manually will not automatically restore the partitions to their former state. Please add the result of `diskutil list` to your question. Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390920/how-to-remove-old-bootcamp-partition-in-terminal?rq=1 & the sidebar for similar questions

Comment: @Scottmeup there is no free space taken previously by Windows. It is already merged into Macintosh HD

Comment: @Tetsujin already did those steps and the space appears again as Free on my Macintosh HD. Edited the post with the ```diskutil list``` in terminal to have a better view

Comment: I see nothing amis with that (unless it's not a 250GB drive). Your data volume only ever shows the used space. The Container shows it all. Example, Mojave, so no separate system partition etc - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR10z.png

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, it is a 250gb drive, and even though there is nothing apparently wrong with it, I am still unable to partition the drive to re-install Windows with Bootcamp. Error above keeps appearing, so I don't know a workaround for it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, only half paying attention ;) Try running first aid from Recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin just finished running first aid from Recovery and relaunched Bootcamp, but got the same error

Comment: @Tetsujin now that I took a look at the First Aid run on Macintosh HD - Data, I got these errors:

error: Cross Check: Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (1) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (0) for extent (0x18536df +1)

error: Cross Check: Mismatch between extentref entry reference count (1) and calculated fsroot entry reference count (0) for extent (0x2963359 +1)

Comment: if first Aid can't fix it, then I see nothing for it but to reformat.